# jquery droppable iframe offset

Tags: jquery, iframe, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout to bind html to an iframe.

The main page contains a draggable and the iframe contains a droppable. The problem I am having is that the item is dropping in the wrong place, e.g.:

The green is where I would like the drop to occur however the red is where the drop actually occurs - it seems to be at the right coordinates but not taking into account the iframes position on the main page.
[image: green - where I would like to drop, red - actual drop]

I have tried applying the iframefix to both the draggable and droppable however it doesn't help :

```
iframe.find('.sim-row').droppable({
      iframeFix: true,
      drop: function (event, ui) {
           console.log("dropped");
      }
});

$('#drag').draggable({
     iframeFix: true,
     helper: "clone"
});
```

It was wondering if there was someway of creating an 'offset' based on the iframes position and pass that through to the draggable so it can calculate its position?

Some fiddles : 
Main Page - http://jsfiddle.net/D26CQ/1/

iFrame - http://jsfiddle.net/cMfMq/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution I could find was to modify the jqueryUI draggable function to take into account the offset:

in the $.ui.ddmanager function add the following lines:

```
        m[i].offset.top -= m[i].element.parents().find("html,body").scrollTop();
        m[i].offset.left -= m[i].element.parents().find("html,body").scrollLeft();

        // iframe positioning 
        if (this.current.options.iframeOffset) {
            m[i].offset.top += this.current.options.iframeOffset.top;
            m[i].offset.left += this.current.options.iframeOffset.left;
        }
```

just before:

```
        m[i].proportions = { width: m[i].element[0].offsetWidth, height: m[i].element[0].offsetHeight };
```

Comment: Just a heads up this destroys performance when using `refreshPositions` especially in Firefox.

Comment: This did wonders for our performance here. https://gist.github.com/loktar00/9233624

Comment: Awesome, took me a while to find this answer, but it saved me hours of searching, or falling back to custom  drag and drop. Thanks, and expect a fat reward soon. :)

Comment: Even though this solves the issue, changing the jQuery UI source is not the best way to go. Consider using this monkey patch: it works great and the author is keeping it up-to-date, too: https://gist.github.com/Craga89/8219459

Comment: @0x2D9A3: How is a module that was last updated back in 2014 "up-to-date"? I have my own version I've been maintaining (which is based on Craga89's original idea) which is located here: https://github.com/kamelkev/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe - this version accounts for iframe and wrapping div scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, but....@kiwijus's answer worked perfect for us. One piece of documentation missing is that you have to specify the iframeOffset when calling draggable.

```
$('.your-draggable-content').draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        iframeFix: true,
        iframeOffset: $('#your-iframe').offset()
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Must have got too excited when I got it working that I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when using a iframe in bootstrap, i fixed it by modifying the droppable class to pickup the iframe and store a reference to it and updated the intersect function to detect when the draggable is over the iframe and will adjust the intersect to match the scroll and offset of the iframe.

Demo here : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10953135/droppable/index.html

Tested on: Chrome, Firefox and IE10

Please see the following for my changes.

Commit

https://github.com/Azerothian/jquery-ui/commit/57456ff345fbd119b63524df2e2ede72502dcf9a

Diff

```
@@ -53,7 +53,20 @@ $.widget( "ui.droppable", {

        this.isover = false;
        this.isout = true;
 -
 +      if(o.iframeFix)
 +      {
 +          windowTest = this.window.length && this.window.length > 0 ? this.window[0] : this.window;
 +          if(windowTest !== undefined && windowTest !== null)
 +          {
 +              this.iframe = windowTest.frameElement
 +              if(this.iframe === undefined || this.iframe === null)
 +              {
 +                  throw "[Droppable] You are specifing iframe fix for a object that does not exist inside a iframe";
 +              }
 +          } else {
 +              throw "[IframeFix] Window is not defined.. lets blow up because we are unable to find the iframe.";
 +          }
 +      }
        this.accept = $.isFunction( accept ) ? accept : function( d ) {
            return d.is( accept );
        };
 @@ -244,6 +257,25 @@ $.ui.intersect = (function() {
            t = droppable.offset.top,
            r = l + droppable.proportions().width,
            b = t + droppable.proportions().height;
 +   
 +      if (droppable.options.iframeFix)
 +      {
 +        var iframeOffset = $(droppable.iframe).offset(),
 +              iframeWidth = $(droppable.iframe).width(),
 +              iframeHeight = $(droppable.iframe).height(),
 +              iframeScrollTop = $(droppable.iframe).contents().scrollTop(),
 +              iframeScrollLeft = $(droppable.iframe).contents().scrollLeft();
 +        
 +          if (y1 < iframeOffset.top || x1 < iframeOffset.left || x1 + draggable.helperProportions.width > iframeOffset.left + iframeWidth || y1 + draggable.helperProportions.height > iframeOffset.top + iframeHeight) // outside iframe;
 +          {
 +          return false;
 +          }
 +          l = (iframeOffset.left + droppable.offset.left) - iframeScrollLeft;
 +          r = l + droppable.proportions().width;
 +          t = (iframeOffset.top + droppable.offset.top) - iframeScrollTop;
 +          b = t + droppable.proportions().height;
 +      }
 +

        switch ( toleranceMode ) {
        case "fit":
```

Comment: Your demo is ridiculously broken on Chrome at least fyi. It doesn't seem to take scrolling into account even.

Comment: Thanks for picking that up, i found that i made a mistake in the intersect and i have updated my solution

Comment: I investigated the proposed solution here, along with the demo provided. While the demo does work, it's somewhat contrived, and cannot be adapted to work as one would want.


The approach appears to be the major issue, rather than the implementation. In this case the OP has special cased the handling of iframe related dragging within the intersect handler, with reasonable results.


Unfortunately the solution is not generic, and as a result several features of droppables cannot be used. It makes more sense to fix the offsets within the preparedOffset method than to special case like this imho.

Comment: Show and tell, my dear kamelkev.. I implore you.

Comment: I spent a few hours profiling your solution, as it really seemed like it would work. While profiling it I noticed that you can only handle the most basic scenarios. For example you are unable to handle a wrapping div with scroll on it (required for using iframes with ios), and I also found that the width/height of elements is sometimes calculated incorrectly. Maybe the approach can work, but as of right now my own solution "jquery-ui-droppable-iframe" (it's on github) works a bit better. It's also not great, but it can handle the edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

This code working for me

```
 $.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets = {};

    // Override the native `prepareOffsets` method. This is almost
    // identical to the un-edited method, except for the last part!
    $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets = function (t, event) {
        var i, j,
            m = $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[t.options.scope] || [],
            type = event ? event.type : null, // workaround for #2317
            list = (t.currentItem || t.element).find(":data(ui-droppable)").addBack(),
            doc, frameOffset;

        droppablesLoop: for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

            //No disabled and non-accepted
            if (m[i].options.disabled || (t && !m[i].accept.call(m[i].element[0], (t.currentItem || t.element)))) {
                continue;
            }

            // Filter out elements in the current dragoged item
            for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[j] === m[i].element[0]) {
                    m[i].proportions().height = 0;
                    continue droppablesLoop;
                }
            }

            m[i].visible = m[i].element.css("display") !== "none";
            if (!m[i].visible) {
                continue;
            }

            //Activate the droppable if used directly from draggables
            if (type === "mousedown") {
                m[i]._activate.call(m[i], event);
            }

            // Re-calculate offset
            m[i].offset = m[i].element.offset();

            // Re-calculate proportions (jQuery UI ~1.10 introduced a `proportions` cache method, so support both here!)
            proportions = { width: m[i].element[0].offsetWidth, height: m[i].element[0].offsetHeight };
            typeof m[i].proportions === 'function' ? m[i].proportions(proportions) : (m[i].proportions = proportions);

            /* ============ Here comes the fun bit! =============== */

            // If the element is within an another document...
            if ((doc = m[i].document[0]) !== document) {
                // Determine in the frame offset using cached offset (if already calculated)
                frameOffset = $.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets[doc];
                if (!frameOffset) {
                    // Calculate and cache the offset in our new `$.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets` object
                    frameOffset = $.ui.ddmanager.frameOffsets[doc] = $(
                        // Different browsers store it on different properties (IE...)
                        (doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow).frameElement
                    ).offset();
                }

                // Add the frame offset to the calculated offset
                m[i].offset.left += frameOffset.left;
                m[i].offset.top += frameOffset.top;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Best solution I found is here: http://maxazan.github.io/jquery-ui-droppable-iframe/

Just link js file and it should works absolutely perfect